# How do I limit display refresh rate on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, kvm-switch, refresh-rate

I have a KVM switch capable of 4k 30 Hz and a display capable of up to 4k 60 Hz. When I connect a new computer with Windows 10 through the KVM switch, it tends to use the highest availabile refresh rate signalled by the display, which results in a blank screen on the display. The KVM switch doesn't seem to modify the list of available modes and I haven't found a way to disable the higher refresh rates in the display itself.

Windows behaves somewhat erratically in this respect, for example when I set the projection mode to duplicate or extend (on a laptop with a built-in 4k display), Windows goes for 30 Hz and the external screen behind the KVM switch works. When I select 'external only', however, Windows would switch to 60 Hz.

So far the only way I had been able to make my setup work was to connect the PC directly to the display, set a low enough refresh rate, than connect it through the KVM switch. In this case Windows would use the previously set refresh rate. The set refresh rate seems to be connected to the complete display and projection configuration, which means, there is no way for me to avoid the cumbersome first step.

I imagine one way of doing this would be through powershell, but typing over a complicated command and executing it blidfolded after connecting the PC to the KVM switch is almost as complicated as the "ritual dance" of direct connection.

Is there a simpler ora more user friedly way to set the highest possible refresh rate on Windows 10?

Comment: What is your display adapter?

Comment: @harrymc it vaires, really. I need a general solution. I get repair/setup requests from friends and relativesquite often, in which case I shove the computer into a tray and connect it to the KVM for comfortable work.